# Detecting changes to MDI child

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to detect changes to MDI child when one of the child is closed?

I'm trying to create a dynamic dropdown menu item in the toolstrip menu item that can be add or remove programatically from the MDI child.

Because of the instance is dispose when the child is close,i couldn't cross check with the toolstrip menu item.The adding part is successful but the removing part is a problem.

```
            ToolStripMenuItem temp = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            if(form.Visible == true)
            {
                this.SuspendLayout();
                temp.Name = form.Text;
                temp.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 22);
                temp.Text = form.Text;

                this.windowsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { temp });
                this.ResumeLayout();
            }
```

Comment: How are you adding? Show the code of your adding part.

Comment: the toolstrip menu item contain only text,name and size.If i want to cross check with the an event handler of formClosed when MDI child is closed,the instance is no longer available for me to cross check to the toolstrip menu item.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FormClosing` event. It executes before disposing the instance of the form. `FormClosed` event fires after disposing of the form's instance.